# Parsing JSON in Freemarker error

Tags: java, html, json, freemarker

I am trying to pass a JSON string from my server to the client and I want to manipulate it with Freemarker.

The json from the server is:

```
"{\"0\": 
{\"keyA\": 2896.42,\"keyB\": 5.682365615075204,\"keyC\": 1044018.3981740332},
\"1\": 
{\"keyA\": 2896.73,\"keyB\": 5.683365542595956,\"keyC\": 1043386.221698152},
\"2\": 
{\"keyA\": 2897.37,\"keyB\": 5.68536539763746,\"keyC\": 1044550.1489558858},
\"3\": 
{\"keyA\": 2909.49,\"keyB\": 5.6803657600337,\"keyC\": 1053277.0319540345}}"
```

my freemarker in the HTML:

<#assign pj = pJson?eval>
${pj.0.keyA}

the error provided is:

```
Encountered "0" at line 894, column 85 in blah/doc.htm.
Was expecting one of:
"false" ...
"true" ...
<LESS_THAN> ...
<LESS_THAN_EQUALS> ...
<ESCAPED_GT> ...
<ESCAPED_GTE> ...
```

Why is this? I have tried accessing the value under key "0" by [0], ["0"]. Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated to the error shown above, but don't use `?eval` to parse JSON, but `?eval_json` (added in FreeMarker 2.3.31). `?eval` can't parse all JSON, and can call methods, which can be a security problem.

Answer (score 2):

That should be `${pj['0'].keyA}`.

Comment: Is there any benefit over using ${pj['a'].keyA} over ${pj.a.keyA}?

Comment: There's no advantage of `pj['a']` over `pj.a`; if you can, always use the form without `[]` as it looks cleaner. Of course, if the key is a numerical literal or a keyword then you have to use `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, similar to hashmaps, freemarker wants a string key.

so i changed \"0\" to 'a' and it worked fine.

Thanks

Comment: Something is not right here. JSON also requires string keys. Also, if the `0` is quoted, like `"0": "some value"`, then it *is* a string.

Comment: I know it would be a string of course, but it just didnt want to work like that. Not sure why at all.

Comment: Well, you have written `pj.0`, and there's no such shortcut in the FTL syntax. Just like in most C-like languages, identifiers can't start with a number... not even after a dot.